# dotnet-ef does not exist - Windows 10 WSL (Ubuntu)

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ef-core-3.0

I've been testing dotnet core 3 in different OS like **Windows** and **Linux(Ubuntu)**. All of them are working fine with EF Core!

However, I decided to give a chance to [Windows WSL - Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) and see how it works. That's why I'm here!

**The problem with WSL and Ubuntu 18.04 is:**

I installed EF Core globally and restarted the terminal. *** Up to this point, the EF version is 3.1.4**

```
> dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

I get the following error when I try to run any `dotnet ef` command:

```
> dotnet ef database update

Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
```

Has anyone faced the same error using **Windows WSL** and **Ubuntu 18.04**?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally I found the solution!

I've tried to export the PATH variable `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.dotnet/tools"` as @kapsiR mentioned. However, it was valid for a single terminal session only. So if I close the terminal and open again, the $PATH configuration disappears.

**The solution that works for me:**

1. `cd /home/yourUserName`
2. Edit the file `.zshrc` and add this line `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.dotnet/tools/"`. *NOTE: I'm using `zsh shell` in this case. You should change it if you are using a different one.*
3. Restart your terminal

Answer (score 7):

Sadly, the `PATH` isn't exported directly after the installation of the `dotnet-sdk`.
You basically have two options:

1. Add the tool path manually for the current session:
   `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.dotnet/tools"`

OR

2. Start a new session of the WSL

With the `dotnet-sdk` there comes a script which adds it to the `PATH`, it's located under `/etc/profile.d/dotnet-cli-tools-bin-path.sh`.

Comment: Thank you @kapsiR. I already tried the first option. However, it is valid for a single terminal session only. If I close the terminal and open again, it is gone!

Answer (score 0):

For use `dotnet-ef` in ubuntu we need run this command to add `dotnet-sdk` in ubuntu

```
sudo apt upgrade dotnet-sdk-7.0
```

or

```
sudo apt upgrade dotnet-sdk-6.0
```

Next use this command to add `dotnet-ef`:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 7.0.13
```

For more information see the references :

[Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-ef)

[Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu)